# Regularization of measures

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to understand a concept of regularization of measure and I have a hard time finding a good reference of the proof of Lemma 2.7 in the attached picture. Can someone please recommend a good proof reference of briefly explain a concept of regularization of measures?

[image]

Comment: The idea at its core is usually first understood through mollifies of functions. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier